# Unexpected Result When Filtering PANDAS DF Row

Tags: python, pandas

I typically filter a pandas DataFrame using the following syntax:

```
FDF = DF[DF['Color'] == 'Blue']
```

I expect to see a result where FDF, which is my filtered DataFrame returns just the rows where the color column is set to blue.  Instead, I get something like this.  Funny thing is, the program used to worked as expected, but stopped working after I upgraded my operating system and re-installed Python and all of the libraries.  Also, it does not do this on all of my DataFrames.  Any ideas?

```
0    Color    Shape    Data 
1    NaN      NaN      NaN       
2    NaN      NaN      NaN        
3    NaN      NaN      NaN         
4    Blue     NaN      NaN        
5    NaN      NaN      NaN         
6    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Edit:  I think the first 3 responses misunderstood the question.  I am showing the result, not the original DF.  My original DF looks like this:

```
     Color    Shape       Data  
0    Green    square      Y
1    Red      triangle    N
2    Red      circle      Y
3    Blue     circle      N
4    Green    square      N
5    Red      triangle    N
```

The result I am expecting is:

```
     Color    Shape       Data       
3    Blue     circle      N
```

Comment: Share your underlying dataframe (e.g. `df.to_dict()`). Also have a read through: [mcve].

Comment: Thank you.  Difficult to do since it contains data that I can not share publicly, but your response does give some insight that what I am doing seems correct, and there is something strange in the underlying DF that is causing the unexpected behavior.  I had hoped that my question would reach people who have seen a similar response when working with filtering a DF, bit apparently it has not.

Answer (score 0):

`('Color', 'Shape', 'Data')` is NOT your column names, but your first row of **data**, otherwise there wouldn't an index 0 assigned to this row. Since DF has no column named 'Color', `DF['Color'] == 'Blue'` doesn't filter out anything, and therefore it would return all records.

If you imported your data from a csv or Excel sheet, I'd suggest you specify using the first row of your file as column names.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question.  I made some edits for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing DF.loc so you are getting unneccessary rows.

Make first row as column header:

```
               DF=DF.rename(columns=DF.iloc[0].drop(DF.index[0])
```

Then use the below to get just the rows where color is blue :

```
               FDF=DF.loc[DF['Color'] =='Blue']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question.  I made some edits for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to filter by a column name which does not exists. First make your first row as column header :

```
DF.columns = DF.iloc[0]
DF.reindex(DF.index.drop(0))
```

Now filter using

```
FDF = DF[DF['Color'] == 'Blue']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question.  I made some edits for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the negative ratings on this question.  However, I was able to work around the issue by assigning a new index and renaming the columns.